# Minimize Energy using Gauss-Seidel method with successive over- relaxation.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have an energy function to minimize

$$E = \sum_i \|I_i - \mathbf N_i^T\mathbf L\|^2 + \lambda\sum_{i,j}\|\mathbf N_i - \mathbf N_j\|^2$$

where $I$ is a known scalar, $N$ is an unknown $n\times3$ vector, $L$ is a known $3\times 1$ vector and $\lambda$ is some scalar. To figure out the optimum value of $N$ iteratively , I am trying to convert the following into a form of $\mathbf A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$, but have not been successful yet.Can some one help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

Lets get this done.

First, to simplify the probem, let me introduce the following vector notations. I will assume that we have to find $n$ vectors  $\mathbf N_i, i = 1,\dots, n.$
We stack all the $\mathbf N_i$'s together in one single vector $\mathbf N$. Moreover, we introduce $\mathbf L^\star $ which is the vector $2 I_i \mathbf L $ stacked multiple times together. We introduce the matrix $\mathbf M$ which is a blockdiagonal matrix which has the matrix $\mathbf L \mathbf L^T$ on its main diagonal. Then, we can rewrite

- $\sum_i \|I_i - \mathbf N_i^T\mathbf L\|^2 = \sum (I_i^2 -2 I_i \mathbf N_i^T\mathbf L + (\mathbf N_i^T\mathbf L)^2) = \sum_i I_i^2 - \mathbf N^T \mathbf L^\star + \mathbf N^T \mathbf M  \mathbf N $

To simplify the second part of your function, we exploit that $ \sum_{i,j} \|\mathbf N_i - \mathbf N_j\|^2 = 2n \sum_i \|\mathbf N_i\|^2 - 2 \sum_{i,j} \mathbf N_i^T \mathbf N_j = 2n \| \mathbf{ N }\|^2 - 2 \sum_{i,j} \mathbf N_i^T \mathbf N_j  $. Note that $2n \| \mathbf{ N }\|^2 = 2n \mathbf N^T \mathbf  I_{3n} \mathbf  N$, where $\mathbf I_{3n}$ is the identity matrix. Using $ \mathbf P = - \mathbf 1 \otimes \mathbf I_{3}$, where $\mathbf 1$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with 1's as its entries and $\otimes$ as the Kronecker product we have $- 2 \sum_{i,j} \mathbf N_i^T \mathbf N_j = 2\mathbf N^T \mathbf P \mathbf N$. (Actually $ \mathbf P$ is band matrix with 1's at every 3rd diagonal and zeros elsewhere). Then, we have

- $ \sum_{i,j} \|\mathbf N_i - \mathbf N_j\|^2 = 2 \mathbf N^T (n \mathbf I_{3n}+\mathbf P) \mathbf N$.

Let us define $\mathbf{A} = 2n \lambda \mathbf I_{3n}+2 \lambda \mathbf P + \mathbf M $ we finally have the following quadratic form

$$ E = \sum_i \|I_i - \mathbf N_i^T\mathbf L\|^2 + \lambda\sum_{i,j}\|\mathbf N_i - \mathbf N_j\|^2 = \mathbf{N}^T\mathbf{A} \mathbf{N}-\mathbf N^T \mathbf L^\star + \lambda \sum_i I_i^2$$
This quadratic form is minimized by 
$$ \mathbf{N} = 2\mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf L^\star, $$

see for example [Unconstrained quadratic programming problem with positive semidefinite matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889165/unconstrained-quadratic-programming-problem-with-positive-semidefinite-matrix).

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old question, but I'm wondering if you could elaborate on the final step, how did you get the final form? For reference, the question comes from this paper: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2024180  "Interactive Normal reconstruction from a single image".
My best guess is that you differentiated the new form of E, with respect to N, which drops the sum of I, and you treat NT as a constant?

Comment: Dear nitronoid, see my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839030/minimize-quadratic-form?noredirect=1&lq=1