# Unconstrained quadratic programming problem with positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, quadratic-programming

I want to find $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$, where $x$ minimizes

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TA x + b^Tx$$

There are no constraints. I do know that $A$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, and $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$. If $A$ is invertible, then the problem is easy, but I am interested in a general solution that handles the case where $A$ is singular. If the solution is not unique, that's ok. I just need any solution, but preferably a sparse one.

Through some reading, it looks like the pseudoinverse obtained via SVD would give a solution, but I haven't seen much theory about that. Would that work? And if it does, can I get a proof? Or is there another way to do this?

Edit: forgot to mention that $A$ is symmetric

Comment: Shouldn't the cost function be $f(x) = x^TA x + 2 b^Tx$?

Comment: Ya you're right. Decided to just put a 1/2 in front of the quadratic term, since that's the standard thing to do.

Comment: by directly taking the gradient and set it equal to zero, the problem reduces to solving a linear equation $Ax=-b$

Comment: And if $A$ is invertible, then we're done. But as noted in the question, I'm wondering what to do if $A$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I'm sure you know, the solutions are all vectors $x$ satisfying the optimality conditions:
$$\nabla f(x) = 0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad Ax + b = 0$$
It's important to note that if $b\not\in\mathop{\textrm{Range}}(A)$, the objective is unbounded below, and there is no minimum.

But if $b\in\mathop{\textrm{Range}}(A)$, one solution is $x=-A^{\dagger} b$, where $A^{\dagger}$ represents the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. If $A=U_1\Sigma_1 U_1^T$ is the "economy" Schur decomposition of $A$—that is, where $\Sigma_1$ only contains the non-zero eigenvalues values—then $A^\dagger = U_1\Sigma_1^{-1} U_1^T$.

A practical approach to solving this problem might be to compute $x = -A^{\dagger} b$ per the technique above, examine the size of the residual $Ax+b$, and see if it is "small" enough to be numerically considered zero---that is, whether it indicates that $b\in\mathop{\textrm{Range}}(A)$ to within numerical tolerances.

If you want to know all of the solutions, then we need to a bit more work. Specifically, $$x\in\left\{y - A^{\dagger} b \,\middle|\, Ay=0 \right\}$$
so we need a way to characterize the null space of $A$. Let's go back to the Schur decomposition, but this time compute the whole thing:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} U_1 & U_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} U_1^T \\ U_2^T \end{bmatrix}$$
It turns out that $U_1$ is an orthonormal basis for that null space. So we have
$$x\in\left\{U_2 z_1 - U_1 \Sigma_1^{-1} U_1^T b \,\middle|\, z_1\in\mathbb{R}^p \right\}$$
where $p$ is the number of zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks, looks like exactly what I was looking for. And using the definition of $A^\dagger$, I was able to prove that $x = -A^\dagger b$ is optimal. I'll just digest the answer a bit and likely accept it. Just want to think a little first.

Comment: OK, but again, it's only optimal if $b-AA^\dagger b=0$. That will not always be the case. In some cases it's unbounded below.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret that condition. When would $b-AA^\dagger b \neq 0$?

Comment: That's just another way of writing $b\not\in\mathop{\textrm{Range}}(A)$. If $A$ is singular then some values of $b$ will not have a minimum.

Comment: OK I see. Well for my problem I know that $f(x) \ge 0$ (otherwise the variance of my estimator could be negative, and then I'd have bigger problems). Thanks!

Comment: How can the quadratic form be unbounded below if $\mathrm A \succeq 0$? Didn't you mean cost function $f$, instead?

Comment: I mean the full objective function. For instance, $x^2 + y$...